# How do I do multiple uploads with DropzoneJS in Rails Active Storage?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am following this tutorial to do multiple file uploads with DropzoneJS but I don't know how to get multiple images belonging to a model to show in the 'show' page. Only one image shows when I upload multiple images, despite doing a `.each` in the`@post.feature_image` array.

Tutorial here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20191223022642/https://web-crunch.com/rails-drag-drop-active-storage-stimulus-dropzone/

Example Repo: https://github.com/justalever/drag_and_drop_active_storage

Changes I have made to get it working: 
_form.html.erb

```
data-dropzone-max-files="10"
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
 <%= link_to @post do %>
    <% @post.feature_image.each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag image %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :feature_image
end
```

Please help- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue with the same tutorial and goal, and I just figured it out!

1. Pluralize the name of your association, `has_many_attached :feature_images`

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :feature_images
end
```

2. Add `multiple: true` to your file field (don't forget to also pluralize the association name there as well!)

```
<%= form.file_field :feature_images, direct_upload: true, multiple: true, data: { target: 'dropzone.input' } %>
```

3. Update your `post_params` controller method to allow an array of `feature_images` rather than expecting one attachment:

```rb
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, feature_images: [])
end
```

That should be all. Some more info here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached